# doesn't echoing content of my php in my hosting

Tags: php, shared-hosting

I Have 2 Shared Hosting.

In both host there have same 2 php files, and its take around 40-50 minutes to complete the execution.

When I Run those script in my both hosting, I watched 1st hosting Echoing everything one by one. But 2nd one doesn't echo anything. But it's echo everything in once after completing the execution.

Can anyone tell, how can I make the 2nd hosting like 1st Hosting ?

I wanted to echo the contents every times, not after fully completing it.

Comment: Do you want to add your files to the question?

Comment: You need to provide code what are you doing.

Comment: http://www1.datafilehost.com/d/80f1eecb

here is it.

Answer (score 0):

Are the two php files really the same? Maybe a `flush` will help.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php